# Can't upload files in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

After I've updated to Mediawiki 1.29.0, I can't upload any file. When I upload a file, I get this error message:

Could not open lock file for "mwstore://local-backend/local-public/b/b0/1.jpg".

I've chmod the folder images and sub-directories to 755, and verified that the folder images/b/b0 is found and writable.

I'm running on Centos 7.5 and PHP 5.6

Comment: Have you made sure your webserver can write into whichever directory is configured as temp directory?

Comment: I don't know. How can I configure tmp directory?

Comment: There is a config variable https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgTmpDirectory that can be set, whatever folder it is set to needs to be writable for MediaWiki.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by changing images folder permissions to 777 instead of 755

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same message

> Could not open lock file etc

In my LocalSettings.php I commented out $wgUploadDirectory , that according to the documentation at [mediawiki documenation for $wgUploadDirectory](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUploadDirectory) will make it necessary to also redefine $wgUploadPath

> There are other variables which are defined relative to this one. If you redefine this in your LocalSettings.php then all dependent variables including $wgUploadPath will need redefining also. If both these settings are not coherent the files will be uploaded to different folder ($wgUploadDirectory) than from where MediaWiki will try to retrieve it for viewing ($wgUploadPath)!

After commenting out $wgUploadDirectory I could upload and use files.